# In Dataframe, how to remove a Column from a Row based on a condition?

Tags: aws-glue, pyspark

I want to remove the column from rows when the column value is zero on that row. I don't want to drop the column from the Dataframe. I want to drop the column from that particular row(s) only if the column value is zero.
I use Pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the records having 0 value in the following manner

```
import org.apache.sql.functions.{col, when}
df.filter(col(colName).=!=0)
```

where `df` is your DataFrame

Comment: I want to filter out the column, not row.  I achieved this by converting the row to json, and deleting the element based on the condition.